# unresolved reference hiltViewModel() despite dagger-hilt in build.gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I'm building an Android app that uses Dagger-Hilt.
Altough Dagger-Hilt is in my build.gradle file as you can see below,

`build.gradle (project file)`:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.38.1'
    }
}
...
```

`build.gradle (app file)`:

```
...
dependencies {

    ...
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"
    ...
}
```

I get an "unresolved reference" for `hiltViewModel()` in the `MainActivity.kt` file,

```
@Composable
fun Home(
  viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
  ...
}
```

I do not understand why ?

Comment: I think you'll need `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose`, more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation.

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem. Didn't think I needed it since I do not use any navigation in my app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

adding `androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose` solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

- I added this dependency in app level gradle file : `implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'`
- Reference Link : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I know it's silly, but for me, the mistake was that I misspelled it like so:

```
viewModel: SomeViewModel = hildViewModel() // not the 'd'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this dependency solved my problem:

```
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.2.0")
```